# debugging with PHPSTORM 7.1 and Xdebug on win7

Tags: php, magento, debugging, xdebug, phpstorm

OK, here is the thing. After spending almost 2 days to find out how to configure/use xdebug with PHPSTORM on win 7 64bit, now I am stuck on how to setup break points in the code and debug the code inside them.

I would also like to mention here that the debugging in PHPSTORM works only when I check the option "RUN -> break at first line in php scripts". I mean when I check this option and reload the page it is only then PHPSTORM picks the connection. And it always start debugging from INDEX.PHP file and never execute or reach to the break points I set in a different file.

The file that I want to debug is inside many folders **e.g. a/b/c/d/file.php** and there is no way I can directly execute that file by entering its path in the browser. So I need to know how can I debug the code which is inside **a/b/c/d/file.php**.

If I explain it more precisely I am trying to debug a function inside "/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php" (its a Magento project). And even after setting up break points in **Action.php** file, PHPSTORM does not execute the code inside those break points.

I will be greatfull if somebody can tell me how to debug the code which is inside of folders hierarchy in PHPSTORM.

Comment: **1)** http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Xdebug+Installation+Guide **2)** http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm **3)** http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/webinar-recording-debugging-php-with-phpstorm/ **4)** http://derickrethans.nl/debugging-with-xdebug-and-firewalls.html  I always use #2 for website debugging -- always works. Quite often it could be misconfigured/missed path mappings (i.e. xdebug does not work with symlinks -- always works with resolved/final paths)

Comment: **5)** xdebug is unable to break on certain breakpoints due to the way how PHP generates bytecode ... so always put breakpoints on simple instructions/lines. **6)** Programmatic breakpoint: add `xdebug_break();` into your PHP code. **7)** And the most important thing when it should work but it does not: **a)** http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log **b)** http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1202

Comment: For debug log settings, not only devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1202 , but in IDE: Help | Configure Debug Log Settings. (Add: com.jetbrains.php.debug)